# Android option menu - one menu item in a single row

Tags: android, optionmenu

I am trying to use option menus for my application . When I add 2 MenuItem it shown in a single row, but i need only one item in a row and other in next row. Please help me.

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tr this code

```
    <item android:id="@+id/last_most_item"
        android:orderInCategory="10"
        android:title="@string/last_most_often" />

    <item android:id="@+id/middle_most_item"
        android:orderInCategory="7"
        android:title="@string/middle_most_often" />

    <item android:id="@+id/first_most_item"
        android:orderInCategory="4"
        android:title="@string/first_most_often" />

</group>
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot. The Android system handles how the options menu is laid out and there are no options to achieve what you want. You would have to make your own View, and then slide this up/down when the menu button is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it's possible but try with the [`MenuInflater`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html) and a [menu resource file](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html).

In your menu resource file, try to embed each item in a separated `<menu>` element, something like this :

```
<menu>
  <item>
        <menu>
            <item android:id="@+id/item1"
                  android:title="@string/item1" />
        </menu>
  </item>
  <item>
        <menu>
            <item android:id="@+id/item2"
                  android:title="@string/item2" />
        </menu>
  </item>
</menu>
```

Maybe it will force the inflater to show the items in 2 separated lines, sorry I don't have the time to test it. If it's not working, replace the submenus with `<group>` elements and retest.

Comment: `<group>` is not for showing separate menu groups, it's for groupping in case you want to show/hide multiple items